# Trying to do a Splunk query for finding the number of same source IPs within a 10 minute window

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am trying to do a Splunk query where I see connections coming in from the SAME source IP within a 10 minute window more than 50 times.  So basically, I am looking for a DDOS attack.

Here is my query now:

`index="*"  srccountry!="Reserved" | stats count by src_ip AS ip_count | timechart span=10m count | table src_ip, ip_count | where ip_count > 50`

But it is not a table, it is an event view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised you get anything at all from that query.  The `stats` command is syntactically incorrect and the remaining commands use fields that don't exist.

Counting events using both `stats` and `timechart` is redundant.  Since you're looking at 10-minute windows, `timechart` is the better choice.

```
index="*"  srccountry!="Reserved" | timechart span=10m count as ip_count by src_ip
```

Once you have a list of times and counts, use the `where` command the filter out those with fewer than 51 connections.

```
| where ip_count > 50
```

That should produce a table, but you can have Splunk display fields in a specific order with a `table` command.

```
| table src_ip ip_count
```

BTW, the correct `stats` command (not that you need it) is `stats count as ip_count by src_ip`.  `stats` is a transforming command, which means it will not pass on the _time field required by `timechart` so that command will produce no results.  Similarly, `timechart` also is a transforming command so the ip_count is not available to the remainder of the query.

EDIT
Here's a variation of the query that may work better for you.  It replaces `timechart` with `bin` and `stats`.

```
index="*"  srccountry!="Reserved" 
| bin span=10m _time
| stats count as ip_count by _time,src_ip
| where ip_count > 50
```

Answer (score 0):

[RichG's query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76049777/10871073) did not work as written but it got me partially there. This works:

```
index="*"  srccountry!="Reserved" 
| timechart span=10m count as ip_count by src_ip where count > 50
```